# Save form element server side

Tags: php, javascript

How do I check and save Server Side the value of the check element (so it saves the input when user clicks back) on these form elements instead of doing this?  This is not working when I click "Back" button.  The check item shows as checked but in reality the action is blank.

```
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="proptype" id="RESI" value="RESI" checked="checked" onClick="this.form.action='?frame=TEST&base=fc';" />
                Residential</label>
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="proptype" id="LOTL" value="LOTL" onClick="this.form.action='?frame=TEST1&base=fc';" />
                Land and Lots</label>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi you can use sessions to store on server side..
It is very easy to use:
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp

Answer (score 0):

The click back means for the browser that just to render the previous page - i.e. use the cache etc. If you do not say that the cache expires immediately then the server may not be contacted.

Answer (score 0):

you may use [$_SESSION](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php) or [$_COOKIE](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.cookies.php)